# Determining the Temporary ASP.Net files folder location for a specific site

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have a server with dozens of web sites running on it, and I'm experiencing bad caching behavior on a few of them. I would like to delete the .COMPILED files that ASP.Net caches for them, but I am unable to determine the specific cache folder for a specific site. Underneath the Temporary ASP.Net files folder location are series of folders with arbitrary names (looks like parts of a GUID).

Is there a way to figure out which folder ASP.Net is using to cache files for a specific site?

Comment: Could you expand on "bad caching behavior" please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HttpRuntime.CodegenDir` property. 
It will return path like:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website1\c2a2b44f\ce865b50

For more reference take a look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.codegendir%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) site.